# Doesn't run oncreateview at Fragment after AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-adapter

I'm new in android and stuck at one step, so really need someones help.
I m code for small piece of program, that should parse Json local file, and post it to activity. Image decode with Base64 to Bitmap and given to CustomAdapter(extends Base Adapter). I check program's steps with Log. 
AsyncTask make all correct, but in method "Oncreate view" it seems to run nothing. 
Her is my code. I m really have no idea , what the problem, help!

My MainFragment+AsyncTask

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

ArrayList<Bitmap> bitArray;

public MainFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    ListView listview = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewPost);
    Log.v("Pl","1");
    listview.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(getContext(), bitArray));
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "YESS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

private void updatePost() {

    FetchPosterTask postTask = new FetchPosterTask(getActivity());
    postTask.execute("uk_news.json");

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    updatePost();
}

class FetchPosterTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Bitmap>> {
    private final String LOG_TAG = FetchPosterTask.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context context;


    public FetchPosterTask (Context myContext) {
        this.context = myContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Bitmap> doInBackground(String... params) {

        if(params.length ==0 ){
            return null;
        }

        String json = null;

        try {
            json = getJson(params[0]);

        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            String[] masPst = getPosterfromJsonAsString(json);
            ArrayList<Bitmap> result =decodeImageToBitmap(masPst);

            return result;
        }catch (JSONException e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Place 5", e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private String getJson(String filename) throws IOException{
        InputStream is = this.context.getAssets().open(filename);
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        return new String(buffer);

    }

    private String[] getPosterfromJsonAsString(String posterJson) throws JSONException {
        final String OWM_NFO = "nfo";
        final String OWM_NWS = "nws";
        final String OWM_PST = "pst";


        JSONObject imageJson = new JSONObject(posterJson);
        JSONObject nfoArray = imageJson.getJSONObject(OWM_NFO);
        JSONArray nwsArray = nfoArray.getJSONArray(OWM_NWS);

        String[] resultStr = new String[nwsArray.length()];

        for(int i =0; i<nwsArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject pst = nwsArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String im = pst.getString(OWM_PST);

            resultStr[i] = im;
        }

        return resultStr;

    }


    public ArrayList<Bitmap> decodeImageToBitmap (String[] base64Image) {
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArrayList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        for(int i =0; i<4; i++) {
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64Image[i], Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap base64Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0,
                    decodedString.length);
            bitmapArrayList.add(i, base64Bitmap);
        }
        return bitmapArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArrayList) {
        if(bitArray == null){
            bitArray = new ArrayList<>(bitmapArrayList);
        }
        else{
            for(Bitmap bit: bitmapArrayList){
                bitArray.clear();
                bitArray.add(bit);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

CustomListAdapter

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private final String LOG_TAG = CustomListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArrayList;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArrayList) {
    this.bitmapArrayList = bitmapArrayList;
    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return bitmapArrayList.get(position);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_post_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"1");
    }
 else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"2");
}
    Log.v(LOG_TAG,"3");
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap)getItem(position));
    Log.v(LOG_TAG,"4");

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;

}
```

}

```
Layouts
list_post_item

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list_item"/>

</LinearLayout>

fragment main

     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="273dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listViewPost" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Tip: If you extend ArrayAdapter instead of BaseAdapter, then you wouldn't need to implement the getItem, getItemId, or getCount methods.

Comment: @cricket_007 Ok! 
But now i have new problem... Now not always appeared this listview.. View(Fragment) creates, all is good, except that listview.. i moved `update post` to `oncreate`, `onactivitycreated` etc
but no listview ( after first launch, all is good. If compile again - no listview..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but in onPostExecute, you are clearing the list in each iteration of that for loop. Basically, make sure there is actually data in that arraylist and then call `notifyDatasetChanged`

Comment: @cricket_007 i changed onPostExecute for this code `@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArrayList) {
            if(bitArray.size()!=0){
                bitArray.clear();
                bitArray.addAll(bitmapArrayList);
            }
            else{
                    bitArray.addAll(bitmapArrayList);

            }
        }`
so it shouldn't clear each data everytime
`notifyDatasetChanged` should stay after `addAll`?

Comment: It should, yes, or if you are now using ArrayAdapter, you can use `adapter.addAll` once you make me adapter a field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Adapter Has Not Any Item So Please change That on Adapter

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return bitmapArrayList.size();
}
```

And also call `updatePost()` methed in `onActivityCreated()` Mehhed

Comment: Also, `bitArray` needs initialized in onCreate, otherwise this change throws a NPE